# How to receive MQMessage using JmsListener

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am upgrading my application from a regular java application to Spring boot application.

I am connecting with an external application, using IBM MQ.

At the old version i got an `MQMessage` object and used only the feedback field. like this:

```java
MQQueue currQ = this.qMgr.accessQueue("myQueue",MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;      
MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
currQ.get(mqMsg, gmo);
System.out.println("feedback: " + mqMsg.feedback);
```

In my new code, I am using `JmsListener`:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "myQueue", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void myQueueListener(String message) {
    System.out.println("feedback: " + ???);
}
```

How do i get the feedback field?

I have no control on the external application that sends the message.

Answer (score 1):

The chapter [JMS fields and properties with corresponding MQMD fields](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=messages-jms-fields-properties-corresponding-mqmd-fields) explains the header mapping. You have two options to access the headers (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52892802/638413)), here is one of it:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "myQueue", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void myQueueListener(String message, @Header("JMS_IBM_Feedback") Integer feedback) {
    System.out.println("feedback: " + feedback);
}
```